# .Net core HttpClientFactory how to dynamically add certificates

Tags: c#

When registering with `HttpclientFactory`,  can only do certificate injection in `startUp`. Is there any way to do dynamic injection?

```
services.AddHttpClient().ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => {
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2("", "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
    return handler;
});
```

Comment: In the future, please pay closer attention to the tags you select for your question. You originally selected the tag for the C programming language, not C#.

Answer (score 5):

For any future users who stumble across this question, I had a very similar need and was frustrated with this limitation of the default HttpClientFactory implementation; I had a very robust HttpClient pipeline with Polly and delegating handlers all chained up, but the underlying certificate that needed to be used might be different based on the specific endpoint URL, and I didn't necessarily want to register four or five versions of the same pipeline for different typed clients nor did I want to have to have the certificates available at the composition root. I wrote a library to extend DefaultHttpClientFactory to add support for contextually applied handlers while retaining the pooling, expiry, and typed client pipelines that DefaultHttpClientFactory provides.

- https://github.com/agertenbach/Ringleader
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ringleader

The DefaultHttpClientFactory uses the named client's name or typed client's type name to uniquely distinguish and track both the pipeline and options you attach at startup, as well as the name that the resultant primary handler will have in the managed pool; for example, a typed client "MyTypedClient" will have primary handlers in the pool named "MyTypedClient" that will get reused and renewed as needed.

By decorating the HttpClientFactoryOptions IOptionsMonitor that DefaultHttpClientFactory uses and hooking in an IHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter during the handler management processes, it's possible to keep all the pipeline stuff working, but create and resolve more granular handlers in the pool, i.e. "MyTypedClient-contextA", "MyTypedClient-contextB", that have different contextual settings, such as a different certificate. The library just requires you implement a couple interfaces to distinguish those contexts and then return a well-formed primary handler for that context when a new one must be created.

This still is not ideal if your certificates are going to be different on every request or very infrequently reused (as you're losing all the benefits of the pooling anyways), but if you have a well-developed typed client pipeline that has a different cert for URL A vs URL B (or user A vs user B, etc.) and you're connecting to them all fairly frequently, this might save you some headaches. Happy for any feedback or comments if this helps you out.

Answer (score 3):

The delegate you are passing in for `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler` is called depending on its lifetime (two minutes by default). So in that delegate you can actually make a dynamic list of certificates (and it will called every two minutes -when you create the `HttpClient` instance-).

You can choose the lifetime of the handler using `SetHandlerLifeTime` (on the builder on `AddHttpClient()`) and choose a shorter time span if it needs be... however if you need a different handler for the same client many times, that defies the whole purpose of using the `HttpClientFactory`.

So I see three options:

1. If you have sets of different certificates, use [named](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#named-clients) or [typed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#typed-clients) clients and assign a different handler for each name/type.
2. If, instead, your http client "generally" uses the same certificates and they just change at some point in time... then set a reasonable lifespan (with [SetHandlerLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.sethandlerlifetime?view=aspnetcore-2.2)) depending on your application needs.
3. If you actually need the certificates to be defined per-request (or per-instance)... then don't use the `HttpClientFactory` or any other client pooling method because you do not want to have the clients pooled at all and you want a different one (with its own handler) per request.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.My requirement is that each request requires a different certificate, and HttpclientFactory is really hard to do that.I think it should be done in the following way: HttpWebRequest request=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
                    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(path, password);
                    request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);